# Is there a standard symbol for "is a"?

Tags: logic, symbols, semantics

Simple question, is there an accepted standard symbol for an "is a" relationship?  I know in math there are the ⊆ - subset, ⊂ - proper subset, ∈ - element of symbols, do I just use one of those or is there a more code specific one to use?

This came up while trying to respond to a statement written as `sedan === car` and I wondered what a better symbol to use for the `===` was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are looking for something like *intensional membership* symbol. You don't want to use traditional set-theory "∈" due to its *extensional* nature.

Right, set-theory "∈" (as well as the set theory itself) is extensional due to these axioms:

1. *∀P∃A∀X (X∈A ⇔ P(X))* — comprehension axiom (in a very naive form),
2. *∀A∀B (∀X (X∈A ⇔ X∈B ) ⇔ A=B )* — axiom of extensionality.

In set theory jargon, one might write something like this:

- *my_sedan ∈ Cars*, or
- *my_sedan ∈ {x : Car(x)}*, or
- *Car(my_sedan)*.

There is not accepted standard symbol for "intensional membership". You can try:

1. *my_sedan : Car* — in a [type theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) manner;
2. *my_sedan η Car* — as used [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=KfrqhEPEO_4C&pg=PA223) or [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=NvAgDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA34);
3. *my_sedan a Car* — as in [RDF 1.1 Turtle Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#iri-a);
4. *my_sedan [cop.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) Car*.